# httpd.conf virtual host changes for apple push notification

Tags: iphone

I have read Ray Wenderlich's awesome tutorials on apple push-notifications from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) and [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2)

Now, in the second tutorial, he is updating the `httpd.conf` file in MAMP server. I have implemented that whole tutorial and I am able to run the apns at localhost. My requirement is that I want to move the PHP scripts to live server, but the problem I am facing that the domain providers (HostGator) are saying that they will not let us update the `httpd.conf` file on shared server, instead we have to purchase VPS level 3 or the dedicated server for this. So, we are stuck here.

If there is any work around or some other available options for this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Saad

Comment: As far as I can tell, they only use the httpd conf to create a new subdomain. There is nothing you have to set on the server to use APNS...

Comment: You can try using the  SetEnv  command in a .htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to edit the `httpd.conf` file. Ray did that for convenience (so that he could keep separate the push notification server and the normal Web server).

If you scroll down part 2, you will notice the following line of code:

```
#define ServerApiURL @"http://192.168.2.244:44447/api.php"
```

Just point it to the script you use to handle notifications and it should work.

Comment: thanx elgaton but can u explain a little that how to point? means any example?

Comment: and one more question did ray's php script is good enough for live server?

Comment: Put the PHP scripts (the "PushChatServer code") on the HostGator server and, using the tools HostGator provides, create the database as outlined in the tutorial. Then, in Ray's code (in the `defs.h` file), change the `#include` line to the address of your server. For example, if the server is at `http://mydomain.com` and you have put the PushChatServer code in `/pushchat`, just use `#define ServerApiURL @"http://mydomain.com/pushchat/api.php"`. As for the "goodness" of the code, the scripts seem OK, but I'm not completely sure (I'm not an iPhone dev, don't know if all exceptions are handled).

Comment: thank u elgaton, it clarifies a lot of things, thanx a lot. i have one more question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486763/apns-running-php-script-in-distribution-mode-on-live-server plz. guide me Regard Saad.