# apns running php script in distribution mode on live server

Tags: php, ios4

every one i have studied and implemented these tutorials of ray
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2

i have implemented apns on local server, now i want to do it on live server, my question is that the script "push.php", which we are running on local server by using this

/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.2/bin/php push.php development

how can we run it on live server in production mode, did we have to ask the domain providers (we are using Host Gator Services) to run this script for us or as ray says

"However, on your production server you should start the script as follows:

$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.2/bin/php push.php production &
The “&” will detach the script from the shell and put it in the background."

means we will use command line interface to run that script on live server?, i am little confused because on server side we use cron jobs to execute the scripts, but this "push.php" should never exit, so i am confused here, what to do. Plz. guide me in this, thanx in advancs. Regards  Saad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the command line interface should be used to run the PHP script and keep it running in the background.

However, as you are on a shared hosting service, I doubt they will let you run PHP continuously.

You may want to try asking them if it is possible; if it is not, just edit the PHP script you cited so that, instead of opening the connection at the beginning and continue running, every time it is invoked it opens a connection to the Apple server, sends the message, closes the connection and exits. Although this is not encouraged by Apple themselves, this would allow your script to be invoked only when it is necessary by the Web server (so that no continuous running is required).

Comment: thanx again elgaton, but please tell me (coz i am a newbie)where i will have to edit the php script, and what editing required for ur suggested solution, i am running that script(push.php) but scripts exit due to $argc value is 0 and $argv is an empty array.      if ($argc != 2 || ($argv[1] != 'development' && $argv[1] != 'production'))
  exit("Usage: php push.php development|production". PHP_EOL); i want to implent your suggested solution , but plz. guide me in this, a bundle of thanx in advancs Regard Saad.

Comment: I'm checking the script in the weekend.